# std::list initialize missing element

Tags: c++

Currently I meet an issue when update Xcode(8.0 8A218a) (This issue doesn't happen with previous version)

The first I declare a const list that contains 476 elements

```
const std::list<int> LIST_CONST = {
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 78, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101,
102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118,
119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135,
136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152,
153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169,
170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186,
187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203,
204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,
221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237,
238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254,
255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271,
272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 289, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288,
289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305,
306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322,
323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 343, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339,
340, 341, 341, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356,
357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373,
374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390,
391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 395, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407,
408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424,
425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441,
442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458,
459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475
};
```

But when I init another list to tempList from LIST_CONST

```
std::list<int> tempList = LIST_CONST;
```

I debugged and saw tempList has 475 elements (missing element 144).
I try to init tempList with another way

```
for(auto it = LIST_CONST.cbegin(); it != LIST_CONST.cend(); it ++)
{
     tempList->push_back(*it);
}
```

[image debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHTO1.png)

This issue still occur.

Anyone did met this issue?

Comment: Can you include the full LIST_CONST definition.  What do you get with `LIST_CONST.size()` and `tempList.size()`?

Comment: Something tells me 144 is missing from your init-list.

Comment: Can you post a MCVE?
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [Here it works](https://ideone.com/emqffC)

Comment: The debugger might be confused. You need to make an actual program show the problem output.